# Multi-processing via TRAMP with asynchronous shell commands

Tags: tramp, shell, shell-command, subprocess, async

I found the following code in TRAMP:

```
(defun tramp-adb-handle-shell-command
  (command &optional output-buffer error-buffer)
  "Like `shell-command' for Tramp files."
  (let* ((asynchronous (string-match "[ \t]*&[ \t]*\\'" command))
     ;; We cannot use `shell-file-name' and `shell-command-switch',
     ;; they are variables of the local host.
     (args (list "sh" "-c" (substring command 0 asynchronous)))
     current-buffer-p
     (output-buffer
      (cond
       ((bufferp output-buffer) output-buffer)
       ((stringp output-buffer) (get-buffer-create output-buffer))
       (output-buffer
        (setq current-buffer-p t)
        (current-buffer))
       (t (get-buffer-create
           (if asynchronous
           "*Async Shell Command*"
         "*Shell Command Output*")))))
     (error-buffer
      (cond
       ((bufferp error-buffer) error-buffer)
       ((stringp error-buffer) (get-buffer-create error-buffer))))
     (buffer
      (if (and (not asynchronous) error-buffer)
          (with-parsed-tramp-file-name default-directory nil
        (list output-buffer (tramp-make-tramp-temp-file v)))
        output-buffer))
     (p (get-buffer-process output-buffer)))

    ;; Check whether there is another process running.  Tramp does not
    ;; support 2 (asynchronous) processes in parallel.
    (when p
      (if (yes-or-no-p "A command is running.  Kill it? ")
      (ignore-errors (kill-process p))
    (tramp-compat-user-error p "Shell command in progress")))

    (if current-buffer-p
    (progn
      (barf-if-buffer-read-only)
      (push-mark nil t))
      (with-current-buffer output-buffer
    (setq buffer-read-only nil)
    (erase-buffer)))

    (if (and (not current-buffer-p) (integerp asynchronous))
    (prog1
        ;; Run the process.
        (apply 'start-file-process "*Async Shell*" buffer args)
      ;; Display output.
      (pop-to-buffer output-buffer)
      (setq mode-line-process '(":%s"))
      (shell-mode))

      (prog1
      ;; Run the process.
      (apply 'process-file (car args) nil buffer nil (cdr args))
    ;; Insert error messages if they were separated.
    (when (listp buffer)
      (with-current-buffer error-buffer
        (insert-file-contents (cadr buffer)))
      (delete-file (cadr buffer)))
    (if current-buffer-p
        ;; This is like exchange-point-and-mark, but doesn't
        ;; activate the mark.  It is cleaner to avoid activation,
        ;; even though the command loop would deactivate the mark
        ;; because we inserted text.
        (goto-char (prog1 (mark t)
             (set-marker (mark-marker) (point)
                     (current-buffer))))
      ;; There's some output, display it.
      (when (with-current-buffer output-buffer (> (point-max) (point-min)))
        (display-message-or-buffer output-buffer)))))))
```

In particular,

```
    ;; Check whether there is another process running.  Tramp does not
    ;; support 2 (asynchronous) processes in parallel.
    (when p
      (if (yes-or-no-p "A command is running.  Kill it? ")
      (ignore-errors (kill-process p))
    (tramp-compat-user-error p "Shell command in progress")))
```

means that if one runs `async-shell-command` once in a TRAMP buffer, then one cannot run another one in parallel.

In fact, if one runs `async-shell-command` in one TRAMP buffer and tries to run another `async-shell-command` in another unrelated TRAMP buffer (representing different connection, e.g. local `sudo`), this will also fail with the prompt to kill the first one.

That limitation appears weird to me, especially the second case.  To further support my point, if one runs `shell` in a TRAMP buffer and runs it one or many more times, one will get as many concurrent shells via that TRAMP connection as requested.  So why `async-shell-command` is the underdog here?  I'm not a fan of running fully-blown shells when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted limitation does not exist any longer. Moreover, the function `tramp-adb-handle-shell-command` does not exist any longer. All different implementations of `shell-command` in Tramp have been unified in `tramp-handle-shell-command`, which is able to run several asynchronous processes in parallel.

This is brand-new, it will appear with Tramp 2.4.2 (planned to be released end of June). For the time being, you could use either Emacs or Tramp git repository to test this.

Comment: Great news!  Thank you, Michael, and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current workaround by the way:

```
    (if (file-remote-p default-directory)
        (let* ((buffer         (get-buffer-create "*Async Shell Command*"))
               (buffer-name    (buffer-name buffer))
               (buffer-process (get-buffer-process buffer))
               (filter         nil))
          (when buffer-process
            (setq buffer (generate-new-buffer buffer-name)))
          (with-current-buffer buffer
            (shell-command--save-pos-or-erase))
          (make-comint-in-buffer command buffer "/bin/sh" nil "-c" command)
          (setq buffer-process (get-buffer-process buffer))
          (setq filter         (process-filter buffer-process))
          (cl-assert (eq filter #'comint-output-filter))
          (with-current-buffer buffer
            (require 'shell)
            (shell-mode)
            (set-process-sentinel buffer-process #'shell-command-sentinel)
            (set-process-filter   buffer-process #'comint-output-filter)
            (display-buffer buffer '(nil (allow-no-window . t)))))
      (let ((async-shell-command-buffer 'new-buffer))
        (async-shell-command command)))
```

It's a synthesis of what `shell-command` does in case of a `async-shell-command` together with what `make-comint-in-buffer` already does so far to establish the asynchronous process via `start-file-process` (see `comint-exec-1`).  Just wondering if this is somewhat better or worse than the stock `async-shell-command` (even for non-remote cases)?  In any case, it works fine for multi-processing via TRAMP.  Why (maybe because of `start-file-process`)?